# Choosing specific DBContext according to database selected in multi-database MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I am trying to build an ASP.Net MVC application which updates database values according to the database selected by user.

How I am designing it is by creating 2 EF DB Models (Each representing a DB). Both DBs are basically having same table structures, just different data as each DB is pointing to a different environment.

A global static variable will store the selected DB (As chosen by user through a dropdown list).

My idea is that according to this global static variable, controller will instantiate the correct DBContext and the DBContext object can be used.

A couple of questions:
- Is my architecture to address my problem correct?
- If yes, how do I instantiate DBContext variable accordingly in each controller. At the moment, instantiating is done at start of Controller by :

```
private DB1 db = new DB1(); //Where DB1 is a subclass of DBContext.
```

Any insights/help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Honestly? It sounds like a terrible idea because of all the redundancy / complexity / security / scalability problems that would introduce but then since you haven't provided any specifics as to the problem space ... who knows? Google "C# repository pattern" regarding your data access. Its better practise to abstract away such things as DBContext from your controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBContext allows you to pass a connection string name.  **If the databases are the same structure, then use a single model!** Instead of having two completely different models, have two connection strings.

Simply use the constructor overload that let's you pass the name of a connection string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx

Then in your configuration you have two connection strings pointing to the seperate databases, and the `name=` attribute that differentiates them.

```
if(userChoseFirst)
{
  db = new MyDbContext("firstConnection"); 
}
else
{
  db = new MyDbContext("secondConnection"); 
}
```

Where firstConnection and secondConnection are names of two connection strings in your web.config.

Probably would be handy to use a factory pattern or have a base controller that handles this for you such that you don't need to repeat it everywhere.

Comment: Hey, yes, using the same Model, and just adding an extra constructor to take in the database string connection name works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"A global static variable will store the selected DB" - do not do this. Static variables should not keep user choices in web application which are inherently multi-user and multi-threaded. If the database is determined by user choice, store this choice in `Session` - since separate session state belongs to a specific user.

As for creating the context, I recommend doing it on demand:

```
private DB1 db = null; 
private DB1 Db
{
  get
  {
    if (db == null)
    {
      db = instantiate context according to user choice;
    }
    return db;
  }
}
```

and use `Db` property everywhere else.

Remember to dispose the context in overwritten `Controller.Dispose` method:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (disposing && db != null)
    db.Dispose();
  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, changed from static variable to Session to store this value. Thanks.